# Libgdx- Music doesn't stop

Tags: android, libgdx

I have an android application for live wallpaper where a user can dynamically play and stop music. I am using libgdx and I am starting music in render() method of my class implementing ApplicationListener from libgdx.

I am checking shared preferences inside render method to check if the play music option is enabled or disabled. If enabled, I create music( if not yet created or if not playing) and if disabled, I check if music is playing- if it is, I call music.stop(). However, the music keeps on playing even after calling music.stop(). I tried to set music.setLooping(false) but the music loop continues to play.

Here's my code:

```
public class MyAppListener implements ApplicationListener, InputProcessor {
   Music music;
            @Override
            public void render() {
                if (shouldPlayMusic) {
                    if (music == null || !music.isPlaying()) {
                        music = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("playback.mp3"));
                        music.setVolume(0.5f);
                        music.setLooping(true);
                        music.play();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (music != null && music.isPlaying()) {
                        music.setLooping(false);
                        music.stop();
                        music.dispose();
                        music = null;
                    }
                }
        }
```

***Odd behavior:***
When my shouldPlayMusic = false/true, and when I go to some other activity, the music stops/continues respectively and when I come back, the music continues to play regardless of the value of shouldPlayMusic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This strange, I can recommend you to delete you condition from if-else part

```
music == null
```

And not create your misic inside render method, for all recommendation you should do it in special static method, for beginning you could do it in your create() / show() method may be it some problem with this condition. Write if it will not help. Are you using Android or Desktop emulator?

Comment: That did it! I created music in onCreate() method and removed it from the condition in render() method. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to listen it